# Aligning header - Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, alignment

Currently trying to align my website logo, menu, and contact us button. (http://bathpluskitchen.com/)

I've tried numerous CSS adjustments but just cant seem to get it right. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Put all of these elements in a container div.

```
<div class="middle-align">
    <!-- your elements here -->
</div>
```

Then use the following styles:

1- Line height method:

```
.middle-align {
  height: 200px; /* 200px is an example height */
  line-height: 200px; /* again, an example height */
}
```

2- Table styling method:

```
.middle-align {
  display: table;
}
```

and create containers for all child elements

```
<div class="middle-align-child"><!-- child element here --></div>

.middle-align-child {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```